# MVC Value not posting back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is weird, or at least i think. I have a simple password change form, which has a control for taking the user input for the password. Now, the problem is whatever the user enters, the view only posts back an empty string.

This is the control on my view

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
```

Model attribute:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 10)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

### Code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Change(int userid)
{
    try
    {
        var model = GetUser(userid);
        return View(model);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //log error
        throw;
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Change(User model)
{
    try
    {
        model = ChangeUserCredentials(model); //break point here
        return View(model);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //log error
        throw;
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

1. removed caching in IE, firefox and chrome
2. tried changing 'passwordfor' to 'editorfor'

fwiw, it was working fine until a few days back, nothing changed in the view or the code in the controller.

Comment: Could you show us your view

Comment: The code you have shown here works fine. If you claiming that `model.Password` is `null` in the POST method, then it because of code that you have not shown us (and caching has nothing to do with it, nor the HtmlHelper you use)

Comment: Here's some more info. There's another field in the same view that takes the user input to confirm the password. It has the same validation rules and is in the same div as the initial password field. That one posts the password correctly!

Comment: Also, model.password is not null it is always a empty string.

Comment: Peter, not sure if I can post the entire view here. Stephen, that is all there is to the get and post method, I haven't hidden any code. I know this is weird, but I googled, scratched my head enuf before coming here.

Comment: You need to show your view. What you have shown works. Its what you have not shown that is the problem and we cannot guess what that is.

Comment: Updated for view. Thanks.

Comment: One more interesting info. In the GET method, even if I set the password value to say "abc", I still see it set as only empty string in the quick watch window well before the control is sent to the view.

Answer (score 0):

add a parameter to your password helper like this:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password,new{@name="mypassword"})
```

then add this parameter to your action method

```
public ActionResult Change(User model,string mypassword)
```

this will work! but it's not a really good way.
if you want to do it right you must be sure you did **Model Binding** right.

Comment: `new{ @name="mypassword" }` does **not** change the `name` attribute of the input and the parameter `string mypassword` will always be `null` in the POST method. _this wiill work!_ No it wont.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounded stupid. But this is what fixed the issue, just in case anyone else faces the same:

1) Per [this](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/repopulate-html-passwordfor-on-validation-errors/) post , I added new { value = Model.CurrentPassword }) to the password attribute in the view
2) I am deliberately setting the password to 'null' in the GET method